# How does one originate multiple edges from a single Graphviz record field?

Tags: graphviz

Having single edges originate from a Graphviz record field is very straightforward and easy to control via ports and compass points.

I have a need, though, to have multiple edges originate from a single record field. The syntax of the DOT language does not appear to support this. Subgraphs may work for me, but the depiction of records is really the best representation of the data records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> have multiple edges originate from a single record field

I'm not really sure why the syntax of the dot language would not allow it. For example:

```
digraph g{
  r[label="<f0> left|<f1> middle|<f2> right", shape=record];
  r:f0 -> {a;b;};
  r:f2 -> c;
  r:f2 -> d;
}
```

The fields `f0` and `f2` have both more than one outgoing edge.

[image]

By the way, though record shapes still work, it seems as if HTML-like labels are replacing them. From the [graphivz web site](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html):

> The record-based shape has largely been superseded and greatly
>   generalized by HTML-like labels. That is, instead of using
>   shape=record, one might consider using shape=none and an HTML-like
>   label.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not using dot directly, I've been using pydot. I'll have to go in and check whether my node label generation code is right. (Thanks for the HTML tip, will look into that.)